# Nested array in Ruby, updates all the array values instead of one

Tags: ruby

I tried to create a nested array, but when I update one of them, all other arrays seems to be updated, What am I doing wrong?

```
arr　= Array.new(5,Array.new())
# => [[], [], [], [], []] 
arr[0]
# => [] 
arr[0].push(1)
# => [1] 
arr
# => [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Comment: It's because it's the same array. You have 5 references to the same array in your 'outer' array.

Comment: What is wrong? You tell us, not the other way around.

Comment: See [`Array.new` – Common gotchas](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [block syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) to initialize the array:

```
arr = Array.new(5) { Array.new }
 => [[], [], [], [], []] 

arr[0].push(1)
arr
 => [[1], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` produces the array:

```
arr = 5.times.map { [] }

arr.first << 42
#⇒ [42]
arr
#⇒ [[42], [], [], [], []]
```